# Automatically calling a method whenever an instance is called

Tags: ruby

I have several classes, e.g., `P`, that share the same instance method `some_method`:

```
class P
  ...
  def some_method
    @id
  end
end
```

Instances of these classes will be used as arguments at many places like this:

```
p = P.new
q = Q.new
...

def some_outside_method(p,q,r,s)
  another_outside_method(p.some_method, q.some_method, r.some_method, s.some_method)
end
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of writing it. Is it possible to automatically call `p`'s `some_method` whenever `p` is referenced as in `some_outside_method(p)`? It is something like `to_s` implicitly called by `puts`, but more generalized.

Comment: What is the point of defining `P#some_method` when you have `P#id` defined?

Comment: The question is not also too clear? what OP actually wanted to do?

Comment: @sawa, you're right. Sorry I was just trying to simplify the case; the actual thing is more complex. This was just an example that came to my mind at that moment. And thanks a lot for help me editing the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce duplication by doing this, for example:

```
def some_outside_method(p,q,r,s)
  args = [p, q, r, s].map{|o| o.send(:some_method)}
  another_outside_method(*args)
end
```

or, more briefly:

```
def some_outside_method(*args)
  args = args.map(&:some_method)
  another_outside_method(*args)
end
```

or, more more briefly:

```
def some_outside_method(*args)
  another_outside_method args.map(&:some_method)
end
```

But don't. Simple code is better than terse and "clever" one.

Comment: where is `some_outside_method` method is defined? who will call it from where?

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is much better.